# How to prettify enum with arguments comparison in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift2

This is what I have

```
let kind = //This returns one of the cases with it corresponding arguments

if kind == .didChangeValue(value: nil) {
             //my Stuff
}
```

this is what I want:

```
if kind == .didChangeValue {
                 //my Stuff
}
```

> **Notice that:**

This is happening because my enum has arguments, I already implemented how they should compare with each other and the `value` has **no value** to me.

So, I'm trying to get it to look more ***swifty*** and less like a **RAW HACK**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check an enumeration value with *pattern matching*:

```
if case .didChangeValue = kind {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, long time no see, this did the trick but just in part because I needed and wanted to check two comparisons in the same if.

Comment: I ended up adding the comparison in a switch case for both cases. Thanks for the tip on pattern matching, was a matter I was delaying to read. And indeed is really powerful.